# How can I handle a socket response with an external process in Rust?

Tags: python, rust

Let's say I have a bash script called `handle.sh` that parses http requests from stdin and then writes appropriate server responses to stdout. I can use that to handle a server with commands like: `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork SYSTEM:'bash handle.sh'` or `netcat -e handle.sh`

So every time a request is made to http://localhost:8080, it uses the bash script to handle the output.

Instead I wrote a Python script to play the part of netcat or socat:

```py
import socket
from subprocess import Popen

host='127.0.0.1'
port=8080
file='handle.sh'

handler = socket.socket()
handler.bind((host, port))
handler.listen(5)


conn, address = handler.accept() # Wait for something to connect to the socket
proc = Popen(['bash', file], stdout=conn.makefile('wb'), stdin=conn.makefile('rb'))
proc.wait()
conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
conn.close()
```

I am now trying to do the same thing in Rust.

Notice how the stdin and stdout of the process in the Python example are neatly and asynchronously set to handle the reading and writing file descriptors of the socket. This is essential to handle the undefined behaviour of the script (because it can't be relied on to read and write in a specific order).

The problem I am having is getting the file descriptors from the socket stream so that I can set them as the input and output of the command.
The error is:

`error[E0599]: no method named as_raw_fd found for struct TcpStream in the current scope`

I'm new to Rust but I can see `as_raw_fd` in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-AsRawFd) so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```rust
use std::process::{Command};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream, Shutdown};


fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    let fname = "handle.sh";
    let mut proc = Command::new("bash")
        .arg(fname)
        .stdin(stream.as_raw_fd())
        .stdout(stream.as_raw_fd())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to start process");
    proc.wait();
    stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Both);
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let host = "127.0.0.1";
    let port = "8080";

    let listener = TcpListener::bind([host,port].join(":"))?;

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        handle_client(stream?);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: If you read the rest of that error message, especially the `help` line, it tells you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based off the comment of @eggyal. I managed to fix my immediate problem by importing the correct trait.

However the title question isn't definitively answered.
Just because it works now doesn't mean this is the best way to do it (yes: I know; I know. I'm handling http with a bash script but besides that).

So in case anyone wants to improve the answer to make it a more idiomatic rust solution with error handling, I'm going to leave my question alone for a few days before I accept it.

This is my first rust programme so I'm sure it's not hard to improve. It's really free reputation since the important bits are already here.

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream, Shutdown};
use std::os::unix::io::{AsRawFd, FromRawFd};


fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    let fname = "handle.sh";
    let fd_in = stream.as_raw_fd() ;
    let fd_out = stream.as_raw_fd() ;
    let mut proc = Command::new("bash")
        .arg(fname)
        .stdin(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd_in) })
        .stdout(unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd_out) })
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to start process");
    proc.wait();
    stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Both);
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let host = "127.0.0.1";
    let port = "8080";

    let listener = TcpListener::bind([host,port].join(":"))?;
    loop {
        for stream in listener.incoming() {
            handle_client(stream?);
        }
    }
}
```